# Laravel Eloquent - Pivot for three tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following three tables: `Permissions`, `Users`, `Clients` (the admin).

`Users` to `Clients` is Many-to-Many. `Permissions` are created by my administration, not the Client, but the client can then assign what permission each of its user has.

Now, I want to create a pivot table for this. This `client_permission_user` would take all three `id` from the tables. Correct? How do I implement this in Eloquent?

In essence, I want to know how I can create a 3-table pivot table and use Eloquent to get my result. For instance, if this was as 2-table pivot (for instance between `Client` and `User`), then the pivot table would have been:

```
client_user
    id
    client_id
    user_id
```

And my models would have been

```
Class Client extends Eloquent {
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}

Class User extends Eloquent {
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Client');
    }
}
```

So what happens when I have three tables?

Comment: can u explain more ..

Comment: I played with such setup once, you can find the code and info here:  https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

Comment: I followed your github, and added all three files. I get the following error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::newTriplePivot()`

Comment: isn't this just a polymorphic relation on permission?